# Set how long a user is remembered with forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my asp.net web forms application I am using forms authentication. I am confused on this thing:

My web.config has:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Welcome.aspx">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
```

and my login button looks like this:

```
    protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AuthenticateUser(UserNametxt.Text, Passwordtxt.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserNameTextBox.Text, RememberMeCheckBox.Checked);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageLbl.Text = "Wrong UserName and/or Password.";

        }
    }
```

`<forms`> has a property `timeout=""` that you can set. I understand that by default that property is `30` or 30 minutes. I thought that this timeout property was to set how long users who checked my checkbox to be remembered would be remembered for with `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserNameTextBox.Text, RememberMeCheckBox.Checked)`, but from what I read online it looks like the timeout property is how long you can be idle on a webpage before being signed out.

If this is true, how can I set how long a user is remembered by checking the `RememberMeCheckBox` with forms authentication?

Comment: why don't you create a method that increments the Session Timeout based on a valid user\password and isAuthenticated.. or you can just increase your web papge Timeout..

Comment: [MSDN: `Login.RememberMeSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.remembermeset(v=vs.100).aspx): _"When the RememberMeSet property is true, the authentication cookie sent to the user's computer is set to expire in 50 years, making it a persistent cookie that will be used when the user next visits the Web site."_ So by default you cannot change that.

Comment: You can use timeout WITHOUT sliding expiration. Of course in this case you won't have inactivity timeout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that by default that property is 30 or 30 minutes. I
>   thought that this timeout property was to set how long users who
>   checked my checkbox to be remembered would be remembered for with
>   FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserNameTextBox.Text,
>   RememberMeCheckBox.Checked)

Yes, you are correct. **[FormsAuthentication timeout  default value is 30 minutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28vs.71%29.aspx)**.

---

> what I read online it looks like the timeout property is how long you
>   can be idle on a webpage before being signed out.

It is called SessionState time out. **[SessionState time out default value is 20 minutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**.

### Updated for the Comment (9/12/2014)

> So if I set the SessionState timeout to say, 48hrs, does that mean
>   that users who click my "remember me" checkbox will be remembered and
>   automatically authenticated with forms authentication on that website
>   for 48hrs? (given my above code)

If you set SessionState time out to 48 hours, after a user logins, the user can leave the browser idle up to 48 hours without logging-out.

So the Answer for your question is No.

In your question, you just want a user not require to login for 48 hours. If so, you need to set FormAuthentication time out to 48 hours.

The following setting sets the **persistent cookie** expire in 48 hours.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms ... timeout="2880">
   </forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: So if I set the SessionState timeout to say, 48hrs, does that mean that users who click my "remember me" checkbox will be remembered and automatically authenticated with forms authentication on that website for 48hrs? (given my above code)

Comment: But timeout will be pushed forward for each hit (by default) so if you access the site each day...it won't ever expire. **Sliding expiration** must be false.

Comment: You are correct that cookie expiration will resets if a request is made and **more than half of the timeout interval** has elapsed. *If you do not access the site for 48 hours, the persistent cookie will expire.* If you concern about security, you can set **SlidingExpiration** to **false**.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do this by using Cookies and setting their expiration date-time. If Cookie exists, delete it. Set a new cookie with your preferred expiration date-time.